# <asp:TemplateField>, with an <asp:Image> item, how do I insert a directory into the ImageUrl='<%# Eval("StatusImage") %>'?

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView with an `<asp:TemplateField ...` > column. Inside that TemplateField I have an `<asp:Image ... >` whos image is dynamically set by a DataSource column. For example:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("StatusImage").ToString() %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The `ImageUrl='<%# Eval("StatusImage").ToString() %>'` needs to have a directory ("Images/") attached to it somehow but how? I've tried everything I can think of... Any suggestions?

Thanks much for your help!
Steve

Answer (score 0):

try this but I am not sure if you need to string be used there

```
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("StatusImage", "~/Images/{0}").ToString() %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many format like

```
ImageUrl='<%# "~/Images/" & Eval("StatusImage").ToString() %>'
```

or

```
ImageUrl='<%# getImagePath(Eval("StatusImage").ToString()) %>'
```

in the code behind

```
function getImagePath(ByVal ImageName as string) as string
  return "~/Images/" & ImageName 
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can best insert the "images/" in the database along with the file name . this will work fine.